# creating Pie chart for my dataframe for a single column with percentage

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

```
import pandas as pd 
data = [['tim', 1], ['nick', 1], ['dick', 0]] 
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name', 'EMI_Paid']) 
df
```

My dataframe has two columns: "Name" and "EMI_Paid" and I want plot a pie chart for column "EMI paid". The column "EMI_Paid" can have two values: 0 and 1.

Here 1 means - Customer Paid the EMI and 0 means EMI not yet received.
I want to show the percentage of total no of people paid the EMI and not yet paid.
and also I want change the label in the pie chart instead of 1 & 0 I want to display as below 
for 1- EMI paid and for 0- Payment not yet received.

Code I have used

```
df.groupby('EMI_Paid').size().plot(kind='pie', legend=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

You  can do :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as  plt
df.plot.pie(y='EMI_Paid', figsize=(5,5),labels=df['Name'])
plt.show()
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for the reply. Actually I want to plot only based on EMI_Paid column and want show the text in pie chart  EMI paid instead of 1 and EMI yet to pay instead of 0.